# Simple inline assembly resulting in segfault when executing "Hello world!"

Tags: macos, gcc, assembly, x86-64, inline-assembly

I am trying to get some simple c inline assembly to work from over [here](http://jroweboy.github.io/c/asm/2015/01/26/when-is-main-not-a-function.html). But I am recieving a segfault every time I try to execute it. I am using OS X so I had to change the syscall numbers. Using gdb I think I identified the culprit: After executing the exit syscall, it tries to execute the part where the "Hello world!" string is stored:

```
void main() {
__asm__ (
    // print Hello World
    "movl $4, %eax;\n"  /* 4 is the syscall number for write on osx */
    "movl $1, %ebx;\n"  /* 1 is stdout and is the first argument */
    // "movl $message, %esi;\n" /* load the address of string into the second argument*/
    // instead use this to load the address of the string
    // as 16 bytes from the current instruction
    "leal 16(%eip), %ecx;\n"
    "movl $13, %edx;\n"  /* third argument is the length of the string to print*/
    "syscall;\n"
    // call exit (1 on osx) (so it doesn't try to run the string Hello World
    "movl $1,%eax;\n"
    "xorl %ebx,%ebx; \n"
    "syscall;\n"
    //"jmp ex;\n" here I tried to jump over the message, which results in no string being printed
    // Store the Hello World inside the main function, results in segfault
    "message: .ascii \"Hello World!\\n\";"

    "ex:" //jump over message
);
}
```

As you can see, I also tried to hop over the message entirely, which in turn yielded no output.

So how can I prevent the message from executing, if this is really what's causing the segfault?

Comment: .instead use this to load the address of the string as 16 bytes from the current instruction' - ohh, that's a bad plan, especially if, for example, you inserted an extra instruction...

Comment: @MartinJames So what should I use instead?

Comment: Are you sure that's the syscall convention OSX? Have you tested with the (OSX equivalent of) `strace`?

Comment: Martin is trying to make the point that you got rid of `"movl $message, %esi;\n"` that was there previously which is a better solution and replaced it by something that is problematic. Any reason you chose to change that?

Comment: @MichaelPetch It would not compile on 64-bit.

Comment: @Jester According to this: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2782.20.48/bsd/kern/syscalls.master

Comment: @MichaelPetch And I just tried it on 32-bit and it gives me an illegal instruction on syscall.

Comment: You should start with an OSX tutorial, not a Linux one. The calling convention between BSD(OSX) and Linux is different.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Ok, but 64-bit seems pretty much the same to me, according to this: filippo.io/making-system-calls-from-assembly-in-mac-os-x I think the syscall executes succesfully on 64-bit, it's just that it also tries to execute the message part. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The calling convention for x64 is different. The SYCALL numbers are not the same. At this [link](https://filippo.io/making-system-calls-from-assembly-in-mac-os-x/) you will see the exit code is `mov     rax, 0x2000001` `mov     rdi, 0` `syscall` which is quite different. The reason it is executing your string is because the wrong syscall number isn't making your program exit, and then it returns and continues on. Also observe the usage of 64 bit registers (like _rax_ instead of _eax_ etc). That code is intel syntax. AT&T style would be `mov  $0x2000001, %rax` `mov $0, %rdi` `syscall`

Comment: As a detail, the main() function ALWAYS returns int, not void

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is based upon the simple tutorial that can be found [here](https://filippo.io/making-system-calls-from-assembly-in-mac-os-x/). I'm now using the 64 bit registers, the 64-bit *SYSCALL* values have 0x2000000 added to them, and I use the 64 bit equivalent of *LEA* to get the address of *message*

```
int main() {
__asm__ (
    /* print Hello World */
    "mov $0x2000004, %rax;\n"  /* 0x2000004 is the syscall number for 64-bit osx */
    "mov $1, %rbx;\n"  /* 1 is stdout and is the first argument */
    "lea message(%rip), %rsi\n" /* load the address of string into the second argument*/
    "mov $13, %rdx;\n"  /* third argument is the length of the string to print*/
    "syscall;\n"
    /* call exit (0x2000001 on osx) so it doesn't try to run the string Hello World */
    "mov $0x2000001,%rax;\n"
    "xor %rbx,%rbx; \n"
    "syscall;\n"
    /* Store the Hello World inside the main function, results in segfault */
    "message: .ascii \"Hello World!\\n\";"
);
}
```

If you are going to *asm* blocks in your code and they are surrounded with other *C* code then you should be using input/output constraints and a clobber list. The best information is in the *GCC* [Extended ASM documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html). We destroy a number of registers (*rax*, *rbx*, *rdx*, *rsi*, as well as *rcx*, *r11* clobbered by `syscall`) and we should be telling GCC that. When using extended assembler syntax you also have to prefix all register names with `%%` (not just `%`). The resulting *asm* block would look something like:

```
int main() {
__asm__ (
    /* print Hello World */
    "mov $0x2000004, %%rax;\n"  /* 0x2000004 is the syscall number for 64-bit osx */
    "mov $1, %%rbx;\n"  /* 1 is stdout and is the first argument */
    "lea message(%%rip), %%rsi\n" /* load the address of string into the second argument*/
    "mov $13, %%rdx;\n"  /* third argument is the length of the string to print*/
    "syscall;\n"
    /* call exit (1 on osx) (so it doesn't try to run the string Hello World */
    "mov $0x2000001,%%rax;\n"
    "xor %%rbx,%%rbx; \n"
    "syscall;\n"
    "message: .ascii \"Hello World!\\n\";"
    : /* No output constraints */
    : /* No input constraints */
    : "rax", "rbx", "rdx","rsi", "rcx", "r11"); /* list of clobbered registers */
}
```

Comment: Nice cleanup. OSX has an interesting solution to the 32/64 bit syscall (0x2000000).  In some ways, I prefer it.  IIRC, you can use eXx regs for xor and mov $1 [if < 32 bits] because it will sign/zero extend.  Fewer bytes, and executes faster.  lea appears to be the only one that needs the r version

Comment: Yes, I'm personally aware that the 32 bit registers could have been used (with the exception of the LEA instruction) but for the purposes of this answer I wanted to avoid the potential questions about 32 and 64 bit register usage ;-), but your comment is correct.

Comment: I almost added a disclaimer [as I guessed you probably did know], but, I also felt that OP might read the comment as well, and benefit.  And, I _am_ your upvoter

Answer (score 0):

Add a `.data` statement before it.  Also, you should tell gcc that you're burning the `eax`, `ebx`, and `ecx` regs, so that any code after will work (e.g. gcc won't put something in `ecx` *before* the asm block and expect it to still be there *after*.

Do this with:

```
asm (
"your stuff"
"    .data\n"
"    .ascii ..."
:
:
: "a", "b", "c");
```

**UPDATE:** The syscall numbers are different for different arches.  For example, for i386 the exit syscall number is 1, but for 64 bit, it's 60.  Adjust accordingly.  Consider including /usr/include/syscall.h and using the __NR_* symbols there (it includes /usr/include/asm/unistd*.h, which have the actual symbols).

Comment: The code tries to invoke the `exit` syscall to terminate the process, so all of that is irrelevant. OP needs to figure out why the `exit` fails.

Comment: He is using OSX so the Linux related help is probably not overly useful.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Any posix-compliant OS is free to define different syscall numbers, based on arch, 32 vs 64 bit, and use various entry methods, such as int $0x80, syscall, sysenter, etc, and which registers contain which arguments.  So, it is somewhat relevant.  There is a syscall.h equiv, I'm sure.  Yes, I'm using Linux, and got a segfault on second syscall, which I fixed by adjusting the syscall number.  So, it's in the ballpark.  Doing the hardwired 16(eip) is also a bit unstable rather than doing lea message.  My pre-update answer was the correct one for his original conjecture

Comment: I'm not your downvoter. but what I mean is that the BSD syscalls aren't prefixed with ___NR_ like they are in Linux, and on OS/X the system headers aren't in /usr/include/asm

Comment: I know you're not, Jester is/was--he took 60 seconds.  OSX _does_ have _sys/syscall.h_ and the man page also refs _unistd.h_.  The issues are the same, be it, linux, OSX, BSD, solaris, and once a solution is given in one OS (e.g. syscall.h), it shows up shortly everywhere.  linux has both syscall.h and sys/syscall.h [slightly different].  In OSX, the prefix isn't *_NR_* [or *SYS_*] but *AUE_* [huh? ;-)], but the concepts are similar.  IMO, anybody doing asm has to be able to read between the lines on this [or stick to java :-)]

Comment: You'd be surprised how many people won't spend the effort trying to find the location of the files ;). I know what you meant though.